# How do you locate an element that appears when I click on something using selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

When I hover over it, it says javacript:void how do I click it. It is like a toolbar that appears when you click on textbox

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML of the element.

Comment: I am unable to locate the element how am i supposed to get the html of the element

Comment: @nnewbietoprog _...hover over it..._, hover over what?

Comment: @DebanjanB the element in the toolbar

Comment: and the element should have it's relevant HTML, agree?

Comment: So you know how to hover over the initial element? The problem is discovering the HTML/locator of the dynamic element because it's added/removed from the DOM?

Comment: As soon as i press ctrl + shift + i it disappears and i cant locate it or ctrl + shift + c

Comment: @DMart Yes i think so

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes but i am unable to locate it

Comment: @newbietoprog So you may like to add the HTML within your question too.

Comment: @DebanjanB the html is way too much of the webpage do i need to add whole

Comment: @newbietoprog HTML of a single web element shouldn't be that big. However you need to start somewhere.

Comment: @DebanjanB i update the html of the web element that is a text box when clicked displays the toolbar